# Gitversion issues with incrementing version

Tags: nuget-package, circleci, gitversion

I have a circleci pipeline that process a net core project and generate a nuget package.
I followed the steps in this great tutorial https://renatogolia.com/2022/12/23/publish-nuget-package-with-circleci/ and I was able to build and push the package.

I'm having trouble with gitversion, so far I'm able to only increment the patch version. I'm using X.Y.Z for **major|minor|patch**.

Here's my **Gitversion.yml**

```
mode: Mainline
branches:
  main:
    is-mainline: true
  develop:
    tag: ""
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    regex: ^dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
  bugfix:
    tag: bugfix
    increment: Patch
    regex: ^bugfix(es)?
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    source-branches:
      - develop
      - main
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}
```

The idea is the following: *Allow devs to create branches from develop (I need to update the regex to allow that), then create a PR and merge that changes to main. Once it's merged the circle ci pipeline triggers and generate the nuget package. The problem is that it is only incrementing the PATCH number, not the Minor.*

I'm using the semver variable as shown in the circleci tutorial.

```
  VERSION=$(dotnet gitversion | jq -r ".SemVer")
  dotnet pack --configuration Release -p:Version=$VERSION -o ./outputs/packages/
```

This also applies to those branches from bugfix. Those are incremented by patch number.
Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

To check CircleCI's Docker container memory usage, you can use the following steps:

1. Log in to your CircleCI account and navigate to the specific project or build you want to monitor.
2. Go to the "Jobs" section of your project or build page.
3. Find the job that is running inside a Docker container and click on it to view its details.
4. Look for the "Memory Usage" section within the job details page. This section will provide information about how much memory is being used by the Docker container during execution.
5. The memory usage information may include metrics such as total memory allocated, current memory usage, and any limits set for the container.

Please note that depending on your CircleCI configuration and setup, this information may vary slightly. If you are unable to find or interpret the memory usage details, it is recommended to contact a CircleCI support agent at support@circleci.com for further assistance tailored specifically to your situation.

References: https://circleci.com/docs/deploy-to-azure-container-registry/

Comment: The answer doesn't seem to be for this question.